# L'Hopital Application Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a twice-differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{12x-36}{3f(x)-6}=-1$. Find the equation of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=3$.

Write your answer in the form $\verb#y=mx+b#$.

My issue with this is that I've tried to simplify it multiple times but I keep irrationally leading to 0=-1. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of the numerator for $x=3$? And the given limit is supposed to exist. So what do you want the denominator to be then? This gives you the value of $f(3)$. And now?

Comment: Write your limit of the form $\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{f(x)-2}{x-3}=?$ and then find $f'(3)$.

Comment: Yes...That $-1$ has to come somewhere in the picture...

Comment: Why do you write L'Hospital's in title when you don't seem to use the rule anywhere in the body of the question? The title should be related to the body of the question.

Comment: @upvoters Please explain your vote on a clear PSQ with a misleading title.

Answer (score 3):

If $$\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{12x-36}{3f(x)-6}=-1$$ then it must be $f(3)=2.$ Why?

Then, from L'Hôpital's rule it is

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{12x-36}{3f(x)-6}= \lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{12}{3f'(x)}=-1$$ from where it follows that $f'(3)=-4.$

So, the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=3$ is

$$y-f(3)=f'(3)(x-3)\implies \cdots$$

Comment: Using L'H to compute the limit of a variation ratio is taking things backwards (or running in circles, if you want), as explained several times on the site. The idiotic mention of L'H in the title of the question should not suffice to lose every notion of logic...

Answer (score 2):

We don't need any conditions on $f$ apart from the fact that $f$ is continuous at $3$ (btw note that continuity is essential otherwise it is pointless to talk of tangent at $x=3$). From the given limit we can easily see that $$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{f(x)-2} {x-3}=-4\tag{1}$$ and this means that $\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=2$. Assuming continuity we get $f(3)=2$. And then from $(1)$ we have $$f'(3)=\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{f(x)-f(3)}{x-3}=-4$$ and therefore the tangent at $x=3$ is given by $$y-f(3)=f'(3)(x-3)$$ or $y=-4x+14$.

---

**Note**: This approach is already given by user "MyGlasses" via comment (which I saw after posting this answer) to the question.